# How to solve Method orderBy does not exist on laravel?

Tags: laravel, repository, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use this package : https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

My user repository is like this :

```
public function getList($year)
{
    $query = parent::findWhere(['year' => $year])
                 ->orderBy('updated_at')
                 ->paginate(10);
    return $query;
}
```

When executed, there exist error like this :

> Method orderBy does not exist.

Whereas I see in the documentation, there exist `orderBy`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe extend the BaseRepository and attach some logic to the parsed result? Some like this comment https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/issues/789#issuecomment-1628792453

Answer (score 0):

If you'll look into the `findWhere()` method, you'll see that it executes query:

```
$model = $this->model->get($columns);
```

So, you'll not be able to use `orderBy()` or `paginate()` after `findWhere()`.

Comment: I try use where like this : `public function getList($year)
{
    $query = parent::where('year', '=', $year)
                 ->orderBy('updated_at')
                 ->paginate(10);
    return $query;
}`. But there exist error : `Call to undefined method InfyOm\Generator\Common\BaseRepository::where()`

Comment: @samueltoh because this package doesn't have `where()` method (check docs).

Comment: Yes, it does not exist. So, how can I solve my problem? If there is no other way?

Comment: @samueltoh if you were you, I'd use Eloquent instead of some crazy packages. You need to use repositories only when you're working with raw queries without models.

Answer (score 0):

findWhere exec the query and get your values using get().

try to change your code to this:

```
public function getList($year)
{
    $query = parent::where('year', '=>', $year)
             ->orderBy('updated_at')
             ->paginate(10);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: There exist error : `Call to undefined method InfyOm\Generator\Common\BaseRepository::where()`

Comment: you can check this https://github.com/infyomlabs
and this https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Eloquent/BaseRepository.php

Answer (score -1):

use something like that for compound searches

```
$posts = $this->repository->scopeQuery(function($query){
        return $query->orderBy('name','asc');
      
    })->findByField('user_id',$dataForm['user_id']);
```

Comment: Please post in English.